# Cyclic Deconvolution

Tags: signal-processing

Suppose I want to generate a vector `y` which when circularly convoluted with a vector `h` gives me a vector `x`. I can find such a vector through the division of FFT as below:

```
y = ifft(fft(x)./fft(h))           // (1)
```

For example:

```
x = [2,4,8];
h = [1,0.5,0];
```

then `y` comes out to be:

```
y =  [-0.8889, 4.4444, 5.7778]
```

I can take this `y` and compute `x` either through cyclic convolution or FFT method and both methods give me `x` back:

```
z = ifft(fft(y).*fft(h))           // (2)
```

or

```
z = cconv(y,h,3)                   // (3)
```

`z` comes out to be `[2,4,8]`.

My question is that, similar to how (3) implements (2) as a linear operation (cyclic conv), is there a linear method which can implement (1) without using FFT. I would think such a method would be called cyclic deconvolution, but I can not understand how to do it.

I understand how to implement linear/cyclic convolution and linear deconvolution - but not cyclic convolution.

Comment: Is this question about the software Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Here is a [method](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/circular_convolution/index.htm) which claims to do circular convolution without using FFT. But why do you not want to use FFT? Here is link to some [code](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/KEse109.htm) which does in using Mathematica `Fourier`

Answer (score 1):

Since convolution can be written as a matrix-vector product $Ax=b$ of a circulant or Toeplitz matrix $A$ acting on a vector $x$, you can invert or pseudoinvert via SVD $A$ to obtain $x=A^{-1}b$. That said, FFT deconvolution will always be dramatically faster than this approach and should be preferred unless the kernel function ($h$ in your example above) has zeros or near-zeros in its spectrum to avoid dividing by zero. Even then, there may be methods for dealing with this particular case that I am unaware of.